# Virtual Users start time

Tags: loadrunner

Is there a way specify a Vuser start-time?
I'm running 10 Vusers, and I want to start each one at a specific time.
During nighttime, 4 Vusers.
From 06:00 till 08:00 - 6 Vusers.
From 08:00 till 20:00 - 10 Vusers.
and so on...

I know that I can make a 'Global Schedule' with the Controller, but there I can specify start-time related to beginning of test, while I would like to run 24/7 with flexible load, without having to rely on the actual start-time.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not supported. I think the best solution is to build the entire scenario relative to some specific time and initiate the test at that time using Windows Scheduler.